# ASP.NET MVC - Entity framework Lazing Loading is not retrieving data from related classes, using fluent API

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, lazy-loading, ef-fluent-api

I have two classes, with 1 to many relationship, but when trying to retrieve the list of objects that is related to the Support class, that list comes empty.

```
public class Support
   {
       public int SupportId { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Summary { get; set; } 
       public virtual ICollection<FileDetail> FileDetails { get; set; }     
   }

public class FileDetail
   {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }
       public string FileName { get; set; }
       public string Extension { get; set; }
       public int SupportId { get; set; }
       public virtual Support Support { get; set; } 
   }
```

My Repository:

```
  public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : IRepositoryRead<TEntity>, IRepositoryWrite<TEntity> where 
    TEntity : Entity, new()
{

     public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Dbset.ToList();
    }

}
```

My Fluent API config

```
public class FileDetailConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<FileDetail>
{
    public FileDetailConfig()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.Id);

        Property(c => c.FileName);

        Property(c => c.Extension);

        HasRequired(c =>c.Support )
            .WithMany(c => c.FileDetails )
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.SupportId );


        ToTable("Support");
    }

}
```

My Controller

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(__supportRepository.GetAll());
    }
```

My View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Summary)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.FileDetails.Count() == 0)
                {
                    <span>No File</span>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span>@item.FileDetails.Count() File(s)</span>
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="@item.Id" class="deleteItem">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

also tried to configure the fluent api in the FileDetail class, but the same thing remains. The list of filedetains returns empty in view

EDIT:

Thats my Support table

[Support Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WGqZ.png)

Ands my FileDetail table:

[FileDetain Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1MX9.png)

EDIT:

I think the problem is the query, it looks like the query is not looking for the related data in the other table. I just can not understand why

```
{SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent1].[Summary] AS [Summary] FROM [dbo].[Support] AS [Extent1]}
```

Comment: Are you sure related FileDetail data exists? Can you post the SQL query generated by your query?

Comment: Sure. {SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Summary] AS [Summary]
    FROM [dbo].[Support] AS [Extent1]}

it looks like the query is not looking for the related data in the other table. I just can not understand why

Answer (score 0):

Since `FileDetails` is `virtual`, I'm pretty sure it will be lazy loaded. So it wont be in the initial query.

I don't understand this mapping:

```
HasRequired(c =>c.Support)
            .WithMany(c => c.FileDetails)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.SupportId)
```

I don't see a `Support` property on your model, can you change it to just:

```
HasMany(c => c.FileDetails).HasForiegnKey(c => c.SupportId);
```

And see what you get?

You also can try `Include` in your query (assuming your not calling `ToList()`, see below):

`return DBset.Include(x => x.FileDetails);`

Another thing, this will load the entire table into memory:

```
return Dbset.ToList();
```

I'd highly recommend just returning the `DBSet` instead, further filtering will get passed to the DB:

```
return DBset;
```

Comment: You were right, my mapping was wrong, the mapping was from FileDetail class , I've already corrected it.

Comment: If i use return DBset.Include(x => x.FileDetails);, I would not be using eager load?

Comment: `Include` should eager load `FileDetails`.